# EXCEL - IF multiple strings in a range of cells

Tags: excel, if-statement

```
Server Type      Count
Enterprise        3
Standard          24
Enterprise Core   6
```

In Excel, I am looking for to check if server type (A2-A5) contains both 'Enterprise' and 'Enterprise Core' or just 'Enterprise'.  If it contains both, then add the two numbers together, otherwise, just display the number for 'Enterprise'.

Comment: What if it contains "Enterprise Core" but not "Enterprise"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps just this:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"Enterprise",B:B)+SUMIF(A:A,"Enterprise Core",B:B)
```

If it doesn't have both .. then it'll only find one to add ..

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUMIF(A2:A5,"Enterprise*",B2:B5)
```

You can use the asterisk as a wildcard in sumif & countif.

Comment: re: Asterisk: Good point, I keep forgetting about that :) lol